# jQuery dynamic selectors show div

Tags: jquery, dynamic, css-selectors, each

I have a set of dynamic headings and hidden divs with the idea that when the user clicks on a heading it toggles the div underneath to show/hide

the divs all have an id in the form "div_x" where x is dynamically generated

Ive managed to use .each() to loop over all divs that begin with div_ and I can .split the x portion of the id, but I'm unsure how to get jquery to get each heading to show/hide only the relevant other div

```
$('#[id^=div_]').each(function(){

    exploded_id = this.id.split("_");
    id = exploded_id[2];

    $("#"+this.id).click(function() {

      $("#div_body_"+id).slideToggle("slow");

   });

});
```

I'm sure someone will be able to point out the flaw here

Comment: Can you also put up some of the HTML to help visualize? Also what is the problem? I don't see a question in here. Are you having an error? Are you clicking the heading and nothing is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is wrong, you don't need the `#` in front of the attribute-starts-with selector:

```
$('#[id^=div_]')
```

Should be either of the following instead:

```
$('[id^=div_]')
$('div[id^=div_]')
```

Also, you can apply a click handler to the entire collection, the *each()* is unnecessary here.  For instance:

```
$('div[id^=div_]').click(function(){
    var id = this.id.split("_").pop();
    $("#div_body_"+id).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

why not use a live function and select using classes? This way you can dynamically add using ajax any number of elements which then take on the same behaviour automatically:

```
<div id="div_1" class="outer">
   <div class="body">
   </div>
</div>

<div id="div_2" class="outer">
   <div class="body">
   </div>
</div>

<div id="div_3" class="outer">
   <div class="body">
   </div>
</div>
```

Then use:

```
$(function () {
    $('.outer').live("click" function () {
      $(this).find('.body').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code is fine except for the fact that ids can't be numbers only.

Comment: +1, except, it would be better to use delegate instead of live.